# OpenTopoMap Lizmap

Tags: lizmap, opentopomap

With the new version of Lizmap you can use opentopomap as base layer, but it doesn't appear in the base layer list when you open the map on the web

Comment: Ticket opened on GitHub : https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-web-client/issues/3671